# Mouse Action SVG

Tags: perl, svg, interactive

Can anyone please provide me a simple example that uses svg's mouse action? I couldn't find any good example online. I would like to show a message when I click on a rectangle. I am using SVG module for developing graphics.

Comment: crosspost at http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1168835

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a little sparse, but you can always consult a package's test files for inspiration.

https://github.com/szabgab/SVG/blob/master/t/09-script.t

**t/09-script.t - lines 39-49**

```
my $rect = $svg->rect(
    x       => 10,
    y       => 10,
    fill    => 'red',
    stroke  => 'black',
    width   => '10',
    height  => '10',
    onclick => "alert('hello'+' '+'world')"
);

$out = $rect->xmlify;
```

**produces svg snippet**

```
<rect fill="red" height="10" onclick="alert('hello'+' '+'world')" stroke="black" width="10" x="10" y="10" />
```

The other mouse actions can similarly be included in the list of key/value pairs.  The complete list of attributes: [SVG Attribute Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)